# bundle external cli with AIR 3.2 for desktop in one package installer

Tags: air, command-line-interface

My AIR project is 3.2 for Desktop. Is it possible to bundle an external cli program to the published native installer ? my air app needs to call a external cli program to make screenshots, but I don't want the user to have to acquired the cli program separately. I would like to bundle the cli program with my air app as an complete package, so the user do not need instruction to get the required cli program separately.